# What SKPhysicsBody to use on scrolling background to limit bottom and top?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a scrolling game, like Jetpack Joyride, where the player is running in a tunnel-like background. I have gravity and jetpack, so I can get off screen if I hold it long enough.

Now when I generate background I use this code:

```
background.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 74) toPoint:CGPointMake(background.size.width, 74)];
```

But it makes only the bottom edge, and I want it also to have top edge.
Making edges with rectangle doesn't work since I have endless background, and new one is added after this ends, so I can't have physics edges on left and right sides.

Here is the image, I want the black edges to have collision properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second `SKPhysicsBody` using `bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:toPoint:` and attach it to an invisible `SKNode` that is positioned at the top edge of your background.